# How to use " the look of confusion" in a sentence?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, expressions, expression-choice, phrase-usage

Can you say 
"I saw the look of confusion on Max."
or do you have to say 
"I saw the look of confusion on Max's face."
?

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way of putting it would be "[I noticed that] Max looked confused."  It's more direct and, depending on your intent as the author, might serve you better.

Of the choices you offer, however, "I saw the look of confusion on Max's face" is the idiomatic expression.  Consider, however, using the indefinite article here.  "I saw a look of confusion on Max's face" is more purely descriptive, and is therefore more generic and neutral.  "I saw *the* look . . . ," however, implies that the narrator not only sees the look but plans to deal with it.  Unless you, as author, plan to make an issue of Max's look, use the indefinite article by preference.

Answer (score 0):

> Can you say "I saw the look of confusion on Max." or do you have to say "I saw the look of confusion on Max's face."?

You must say, "I saw the look of confusion on Max's face."

You could also say, "I saw Max's look of confusion."

The reason as I see it is that 'on Max' is far too wide. The mental image it gives (to me at least) is that the look is spread all over Max's body.

I say this as a native speaker. I would like to provide independent evidence but your example is very specific so I don't think evidence would be easy to find.

Comment: I think you could say *I saw the look of confusion in Max*. *You could also say *...in Max's face*. But simply *...on Max* doesn't sound idiomatic to me.

Comment: @WS2, yes I agree. However I think that how you parse it is important. I don't think it is, "I saw the *look-of-confusion* that was inside Max". I scan that as, "I saw the outward look that represented *confusion-inside-Max*.